# Understanding Connectors ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am new in ActiveMQ Artemis

I have read doc and found **connectors**    are used    by  a   client  to  define how  it  connects    to  a   server.

I have a broker.xml file which have following peace of code

```
     <connectors>
             <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</connector>
             <!-- connector to the server1 -->
             <connector name="server1-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:9616</connector>
          </connectors>
   <!-- Acceptors -->
      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</acceptor>
      </acceptors>
```

so here acceptor is saying,Hey you can connect with  me on port 61617, I am listening on it(which is making sense for me)
but what about role of connector in this broker.xml.
Connector is targeting same port(tcp://0.0.0.0:61616) as in acceptor,
 I want to understand it what is it port means which is mentioned in Connector, can some please explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you happen to read [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/configuring-transports.html) on this subject?  There is a section titled "Understanding Connectors" which should answer most, if not all, of your questions.  I'll quote the most salient parts:

> Whereas acceptors are used on the server to define how we accept connections, connectors are used to define how to connect to a server.
>
> A `connector` is used when the server acts as a client itself, e.g.:
>
> - When one server is bridged to another
> - When a server takes part in a cluster
>
> In these cases the server needs to know how to connect to other servers. That's defined by `connectors`.

Comment: hi Justin
I have created 2 instances of Artemis using docker
i have added line of code in broker.xml of one instance
  ```<connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0.:9616</connector>
      </connectors>```
and
 ```<acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</acceptor>```
acceptor is fine but connector is not working with ```tcp://0.0.0.0:61616```
but when i am changing 0.0.0.0 with my ip address, it working.
So i am confused why acceptor is working with 0.0.0.0, where i need ip address for connector.

Comment: The address "0.0.0.0" is a meta-address.  In the context of a listener (e.g. an Artemis acceptor) it means that the listener will listen for connections on all local addresses.  In the context of a connector I don't believe it really has a meaning.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0 for more info.

Comment: thanks justin, but it still confusing me, can you please guide me, how can i create a cluster of Artemis using docker ?

Comment: This question is about understanding connectors, not creating an Artemis cluster using Docker.  I recommend you create a new question about the specific issue your facing.