# ArtemisMQ Connector

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm new to ArtemisMQ and absolutely don't understand the sense of `connectors`.

Why is `connector` essential, as we already specify `accepter` of Broker Server in broker.xml -> we know which port (it is `accepter` port) to send a request to if we want to connect to this server. Even if this server is part of cluster, what is a role of `connector`? There is also information [from other part of documentation about "Clusters"](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/clusters.html), but there is words about **cluster** connections :

> The cluster is formed by each node declaring cluster connections to other nodes in the core configuration file broker.xml. When a node forms a cluster connection to another node, internally it creates a core bridge (as described in Core Bridges) connection between it and the other node, this is done transparently behind the scenes - you don't have to declare an explicit bridge for each node. These cluster connections allow messages to flow between the nodes of the cluster to balance load.

From [documentation "Understanding Connectors"](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/configuring-transports.html):

> connectors are used by a client to define how it connects to a server.

What does it mean "define how"?

I've already read  and [another question about connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516209/understanding-connectors-activemq-artemis), but it doesn't help me.

Additional questions:

- Is connector always the same as acceptor(I've downloaded some official examples and all of them(that i've seen) have both same acceptor and connector )?
- What information does connector encapsulates, if it only consists of host+port (and it is same as acceptor's (if we omit that acceptor host can me 0.0.0. or localhost))?
- Why does stand-alone Broker have connector, for example by default creation `./artemis create`?
- What should we write in connector?
- Can you give a simple example when acceptor and connector are
  different?

Comment: Related question: what should we write in connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two important points to note:

- A `connector` is **not essential** depending on your use-case. You'll find that the default `broker.xml` doesn't have any `connector` elements defined. For example, if you just run `./artemis create` the generated `broker.xml` will *not* have any `connector` elements.
- The documentation you cited is quite old (from the very first release of Artemis). You may benefit from reading the [latest documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html) which has been updated for clarity in many places.

---

As noted in both the documentation and the other Stack Overflow answer you cited, certain components in the broker need to connect to *other* brokers (e.g. core bridges, cluster-connections, etc.). A `connector` encapsulates the information necessary for these other components to make the connections they need. It's really as simple as that.

Now regarding your individual questions...

> Even if this server is part of cluster, what is a role of connector?

In the case of a cluster using a `broadcast-group` and a `discovery-group` each node in the cluster needs to broadcast to all the *other* nodes in the cluster how the other nodes can connect to itself. It does this by broadcasting a `connector` which is referenced in the `cluster-connection` configuration. When the other nodes in the cluster receive this broadcast they take the `connector` information and use it to connect back to the node which broadcast it originally. In this way nodes can dynamically discover and connect to each other. It's also worth noting that in this case the `connector` configuration will essentially mirror one of the broker's `acceptor` configurations (since the `connector` will be used by other nodes to connect to the broadcasting node's `acceptor`). This is discussed further in the [cluster documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html).

> ...connectors are used by a client to define how it connects to a server...

This bit of documentation you quoted is accurate but may be a bit confusing. Keep in mind that that a *client* can run anywhere, even within the broker itself. In the case of core bridges and cluster connections there is a client running in the broker which use the `connector` to determine how to connect to another broker. For what it's worth the updated documentation doesn't have this specific wording.

> What does it mean "define how"?

A `connector` is the URL that the client needs to connect to the broker. The URL can simply include the host and port or it can contain lots of configuration details for the connection (e.g. SSL config).

> Is connector always the same as acceptor..?

No, not *always*. In the case of a cluster they will be the same (or very close) for the reasons I already outlined, but in the case of a bridge they won't be the same.

> What information does connector encapsulates..?

See above.

> Why does stand-alone Broker have connector, for example by default creation `./artemis create`?

It doesn't. See above.

> What should we write in connector?

The URL needed to connect.

> Can you give a simple example when acceptor and connector are different?

As mentioned previously, bridging is an example where different acceptors and connectors are used. ActiveMQ Artemis ships with a "core-bridge" example in the `examples/features/standard` directory which demonstrates different acceptors and connectors. The example involves 2 different brokers with one broker having a core bridge configured to send messages to the other broker. [Here's the `broker.xml`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/features/standard/core-bridge/src/main/resources/activemq/server0/broker.xml) with the bridge defined. You can see the acceptor listening on the `localhost:61616` and the connector for `localhost:61617`. This connector points to the other broker which is [listening on `localhost:61617`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/features/standard/core-bridge/src/main/resources/activemq/server1/broker.xml#L32).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand, that broker can be both server and client(to connect to other broker in cluster). However, there are other questions : Is connector always the same as acceptor(I've downloaded some official examples and all of them(that i've seen) have both same acceptor and connector )? What information does connector encapsulates, if it only consists of host+port(and it is same as acceptor's(if we omit that acceptor host can me 0.0.0. or localhost))? Why does stand-alone Broker have connector, for example by default creation ./artemis create

Comment: Thanks for lots of information! I think, it help me to understand this topic a bit clearer. I edited  my question and asking for an example of different acceptor/connector. I`ll be glad, if you help me.